# Using Registry Values in ICON Section

Tags: icons, inno-setup

I am trying to use a registry value for the location of an EXE file in the ICONS section, the value is not located in the normal \microsoft\windows\exe\ registry. I have the following code that is not retuning the value, the ICON is created with the word "computer" for the target.

```
function GetACADexe (Param: string): string;
var VerKey: String;
var ExeKey: String;
begin
    if RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, 'Software\Classes\AutoCAD.Drawing', 'CurVer', VerKey) and
         RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, 'Software\Classes\' + VerKey + '\Protocol\StdFileEditing', 'Server', ExeKey) then
        Result := ExpandConstant ('{ExeKey}')     
 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the resultant working answer;

```
function GetHKCU() : Integer;
begin
 if IsWin64 then
  begin
    Result := HKCU64;
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
  end;
end;

function GetACADexe(Value: String): string;
var
  VerKey: string;
  ExeKey: string;
begin
  // result should be initialized for case when ACAD is not installed
  Result := '';
  if RegQueryStringValue(GetHKCU(), 'Software\Classes\AutoCAD.Drawing\CurVer', '', VerKey) and
     RegQueryStringValue(GetHKCU(), 'Software\Classes\' + VerKey + '\Protocol\StdFileEditing\Server', '', ExeKey)
  then
    Result := ExeKey;
end;
```

Along with checking for 32 or 64 bit systems, I also ran into the issue that the registry values where the "(Default)" values, that's why the empty '' for the key name.  Works great now.... Thanks TLAMA.